# MIPS assembly matrix summation

Tags: assembly, mips

im trying to sum two matrix i already have the following code. How can i make the result looks like matrix instead of ordinary array? I'm trying to make a newline with endl:   .asciiz "\n" but i dont know how to make newline after the number i want

```
    .data
difference: .asciiz "Array[C]: "            #store string to difference
arrayA: .word 10, 3, 7, 
        .word 1, 12, 20, 
        .word 16, 18, 11    #Array1 to store the first list
arrayB: .word 3, 4, 2, 
        .word 8, 4, 1, 
        .word 7, 9, 10      #Array2 to store the second list

arrayC: .space 10   #ArraySum to store the sum of  Array1 and Array2
endl:   .asciiz "\n"
.text
main:   
    la $t1, arrayA      #$t1 = address of arrayA
    la $t2, arrayB      #$t2 = address of arrayB
    la $t3, arrayC      #$t3 = address of arrayC

    li $t4, 0       #setting $t4 = 0; t4 will serve as a counter
    li $s1, 9       #setting $s1 = 10

    li $v0, 4       #printing out strings
    la $a0, difference  #print out the actual string
    syscall         #system call

    j loop          #jump to loop

loop:
    beq $t4, $s1, final #if $t1 == $s1, then go to final 
    lw $t5, 0($t1)      #get value from array cell and store in $t5
    lw $t6, 0($t2)      #get value from array cell and store in $t6

    add $t7, $t5, $t6   #add $t5 with $t6 and store it in $t7

    sw $t7, 0($t3)      #store $t7 into the address of $t8

    li $v0, 1       #print integer
    move $a0, $t7       #move $t7 into $a0
    syscall         #system call

    li $a0, 32      #print the ASCII representation of 32 which is space
    li $v0, 11      #system call for printing character
    syscall         #system call

    addi $t1, $t1, 4    #incrementing $t1 by 4
    addi $t2, $t2, 4    #incrementing $t2 by 4
    addi $t4, $t4, 1    #incrementing $t1 by 1

    syscall 
    j loop          #go back through the loop

final:
    li $v0, 10
    syscall         #end the program
```

Comment: So print that newline after every 3 numbers. Any problems with that?

Comment: i'm totally beginner in MIPS and actually even that is a problem

Comment: Increment a counter. When it hits 3, print the newline, reset the counter. Is that enough hint?